# How to get URL/path to embedded file in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having trouble being able to access .mp4 files embedded within my Xamarin.Forms project. According to the [File Handling in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/files?tabs=vswin) documentation, it says,

> The path of the file on each platform can be determined from a .NET
>   Standard library by using a value of the `Environment.SpecialFolder`
>   enumeration as the first argument to the `Environment.GetFolderPath`
>   method. This can then be combined with a filename with the
>   `Path.Combine` method.

I've also followed the instructions on the page that tell you to make sure you set the "Build Action" to "EmbeddedResource" for the files. Ultimately I'm trying to get the path/url of the file so that I can pass it into [MediaManager](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager)'s `CrossMediaManager.Current.Play()` function. Here's some code that has continuously failed, no matter how much I tweak it. Most of this was taken directly from the Xamarin documentation linked above:

```
// Gets the path to the video file.
string fileDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData);
string file = "Signing.video.banana.mp4";
string pathToFile = Path.Combine(fileDirectory, file);

// Print some info about the file and its directory
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pathToFile);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(File.Exists(pathToFile));
```

The .mp4 file is located in a folder called "video" that's directly within the Project "Signing." I've tried adjusting the file path so that it's just the file, it's just the file and video folder, and I've tried using '/' instead of '.' to separate the directories. The printout I always get is that the file doesn't exist. The path that's printed always looks something like this when running it on an iOS emulator:

```
/Users/doug/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/FD9E9045-EF6A-4ECA-9192-25CEC0E7C23C/data/Containers/Data/Application/AF92806E-C68F-45ED-814D-C383821F470A/Documents/Signing.video.banana.mp4
```

I've seen suggestions saying to append "file://" to the front of the file path, as well as other similar suggestions. Nothing works. How do I embed a file in Xamarin.Forms and later retrieve its file path?

Comment: For iOS, include the file in the root of your iOS project, set the build action to Content, and then the path will be "file.ext" or "./file.ext"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to copy the assembly embedded resource to a temp file in order for MediaManager to play it.

Using `Xamarin.Essentials` you can obtain the OS's cache directory and then copy the resource to it and play it via a `file://` url.

#### Example:

```
var cacheFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, "cached.mp4");
if (File.Exists(cacheFile))
    File.Delete(cacheFile);
using (var resource = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("YourFullEmbeddedResourceResourceID.mp4"))
using (var file = new FileStream(cacheFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
{
    resource.CopyTo(file);
}
await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(new MediaFile("file://localhost/" + cacheFile, MediaFileType.Video, ResourceAvailability.Local));
```

**Note:** Personally I would not use embedded resources as they bloat your assemblies (or .text segments in native libraries) and thus consume application memory, cause slower load times, etc.., but use the native bundle/asset based files and copy those to the cache dir. You can use Xamarin.Essentials to obtain those read-only bundled/asset files via `OpenAppPackageFileAsync` and use that stream to copy the file to the cache dir.