# Xamarin SQLite DB errors (embedded resource)

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to *query* SQLite **embedded resources**, but I am having a very hard time. The problem is the infamous "cannot find table", but it seems I am looking in the wrong direction.

First, this is my current code:

```
        string filename = "Testing.CSV." + items[category][subcategory].file + "-" + App.current_language + ".db3";

        var conn = new SQLiteConnection(filename);

        var o = conn.GetTableInfo("Items");
        var q = conn.Table<Items>().Where(x => (x.thenumber > 3 && x.thenumber < 20));

        List<Items> u = conn.Table<Items>().ToList();
        foreach(var i in q)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("LINQ returned int {0} string '{1}'", i.thenumber, i.thelabel);
        }

        var p = conn.Query<int>("select thenumber from Items where thenumber > 3 and thenumber< 20 order by random() limit 1;", 1);
```

Adding the `conn.CreateTable<Items>();` after creating the connection won't help a bit, except masking an error: I don't get a null pointer, but **I don't get any results from any queries** you see above.

Changing the path of the DB to the following also does not matter:

```
        var embeddedResourceDbStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(filename);
        var dbPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), filename);

        var conn = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
```

Note that I have the same query on a **text file** (embedded resource, also) and it works like a charm:

```
        string filename = "Testing.CSV." + items[category][subcategory].file + "-" + App.current_language + ".txt";

        var assembly = IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(typeof(TestPage)).Assembly;
        Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(filename);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);

        // Good old CSV, at least I can open it
        List<string> lines = new List<string>(2);

        // Load all its contents and query
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            string s = reader.ReadLine();

            // ...
```

Casting away any doubts, the SQLite DB is there and working, and at least the manual query works in the shell:

```
% sqlite3 /Users/sensei/Documents/Projects/playground/Testing/Testing/CSV/Test-en.db3 
SQLite version 3.24.0 2018-06-04 19:24:41
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> select thenumber from Items where thenumber > 3 and thenumber< 20 order by random() limit 1;
19
sqlite> select thenumber from Items where thenumber > 3 and thenumber< 20 order by random() limit 1;
17
sqlite> select thenumber from Items where thenumber > 3 and thenumber< 20 order by random() limit 1;
8
sqlite> select thenumber from Items where thenumber > 3 and thenumber< 20 order by random() limit 1;
5
sqlite>
```

Am I missing something terribly obvious that I am unable so see?

Comment: You need to copy that Sqlite file out of the assembly and save it to its own file and then create a Connection to it.

Comment: I don’t get it. Are you saying that every time I start the app a DB will be copied and opened? It makes no sense, why is SQLite different from a CSV?

Comment: In the CVS case, you are streaming into *memory* as the text file is just a continuous sequence of bytes. In the case of SQLite, the Sqlite engine need access to the file (r/o r/w) as a db file is not a simple sequence of bytes, but a complex internal structure (metadata, indexes, tables, etc...) In terms of start up (say we are using the cache dir), if the cached DB file does not exist, copy it, if it exists do not, and proceed to open a connection to the file. Similar example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52635317/how-to-get-url-path-to-embedded-file-in-xamarin-forms/52635579#52635579

Comment: Still I don’t understand why. If the DB is in memory then I would say it should make no difference between a CSV and a DB, loading it from a stream should do the trick. I don’t know if this is possible, though.

Comment: Yes, those two are very different, period...  Sqlite supports `:memory:` based DBs, but they are not structured 100% compatible with a file-based one and while you could hack the C-level API to allow it to "attach" to an arbitrary memory block that contains a memory snapshot, that is not supported out of the box. You could create a `:memory:` DB, create your tables and the create your rows from that CVS file if you needed, but as a `:memory:` DB is lost when the final connection is closed (or lost), you would need to do it each time during app startup.